# What do I make my CosmosDB parition key when my JSON top level token is variable?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am confused what to make my CosmosDB partition key when my JSON looks like this

```
{
    "AE": [
        {
            "storeCode": "XXX",
            "storeClass": "YYY"
        }
     ],
"AT": [
        {
            "storeCode": "ZZZ",
            "storeClass": "XYZ"
        }
     ]
}
```

Normally the top level would be country:AT and so on and I would make the partition key /country but in this case I have nothing to use on the top level so what do I do?

the JSON comes from a third party so I dont have the option to change it at source.

Answer (score 0):

Since i did not find any statements about the [partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data) for sub-array in the official document. I could only provide you with a similar thread for your reference :[CosmosDB - Correct Partition Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768663/cosmosdb-correct-partition-key)

Here is some explanations by @Mikhail:

> Partition Key has to be a single value for each document, it can't be
>   a field in sub-array. Partition Key is used to determine which
>   database node will host your document, and it wouldn't be possible if
>   you specified multiple values, of course.
>
> If your single document contains data from multiple entities, and you
>   will query those entities separately, it might make sense to split
>   your documents per entity. If all those "radars" are related to some
>   higher level entity, use that entity ID as partition key.

For rigor,i would suggest you contacting with azure cosmos team to check whether this feature is not supported yet so far,whether will be implemented in the future.

Comment: I will ask them and in mean time just wrap the document in an envelope

Comment: @MattDouhan Ok,if any updates,you could post here. I think this is a common requirement,so maybe it's helpful for others.

Comment: will do once they respond